Vue 3 Router warning when using child routes with parameter
I have routes like the following (simplified)
routes: [
{
  path: 'tasks',
  children: [
  {
    path: ':id',
    children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'tasks.show',
      components: {
        default: () => import('../views/Tasks/ShowView.vue')
      }
    }
  }
]

and get the id on component side with
const taskId = route.params.id

Now my console complains
[Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s) "taskId" when navigating. See https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22 for more details.

From the link I understand that I should not misuse params that are not defined in the path. But it is defined. Just not within the very level of nesting. Everything works fine - how do I get rid of the warning?

You've not defined a param called taskId on any of your routes (you have only one called id), so any use of taskId in route navigation is incorrect.  What navigation code do you run to generate the warning, i.e. a router.push() or something else?  Please add it to the question.

The warning appeared on entering or refreshing the page. Your question on where the warning was generated made me search deeper. The problem was a link further down on that page:
<RouterLink :to="{ name: 'admin.tasks.entries.create', params: { taskId } }">
instead of
<RouterLink :to="{ name: 'admin.tasks.entries.create', params: { id: taskId } }">
Thank you and no thanks to Copilot <.<
